# evaluate the derivative of a definition on python

Tags: python, sympy

I am new in python, I would like to create a function that returns the derivative of a function and that it can be evaluated numerically, for example

```
def func(x, y, z):
    x = sympy.Symbol('x')
    y = sympy.Symbol('y')
    z = sympy.Symbol('z');
    ff1 = sympy.sin(x * y * z)
    ff2 = sympy.Derivative(ff1, x)
    return ff2
func(1, 2, 3)
```

This definition does not work, How could this be done?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to evaluate it **numerically**, then `sympy` is not the correct approach. Use `numpy` with `diff` or gradient instead. `sympy` evaluates the derivative symbolically.

Comment: Can you clarify what you intended this function to do? You are not actually using any of its input, just replacing it immediately. What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate a derivate symbolically using `sympy`, either use the `diff` function or call the `doit` method on the `Derivative` object:

evaluate the derivative object:

```
def func(x, y, z):
    xs, ys, zs = sympy.symbols('x y z')
    ff1 = sympy.sin(xs * ys * zs)
    ff2 = sympy.Derivative(ff1, xs)
    return ff2
my_derivative = func(1, 2, 3)
my_derivative.doit()
```

or differentiate directly:

```
def func2(x, y, z):
    xs, ys, zs = sympy.symbols('x y z')
    ff1 = sympy.sin(xs * ys * zs)
    ff2 = sympy.diff(ff1, xs)
    return ff2
func2(1, 2, 3)
```

Both give the correct result:

```
# Out: y*z*cos(x*y*z)
```

If you want to get the result of the derivative, you have to evaluate it:

```
def func_eval(x, y, z):
    xs, ys, zs = sympy.symbols('x y z')
    ff1 = sympy.sin(xs * ys * zs)
    ff2 = sympy.diff(ff1, xs)
    der_eval = ff2.evalf(subs={xs: 1, ys: 2, zs: 3})
    return der_eval
func_eval(1, 2, 3)
# Out: 5.7610217199022
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what is desired. It still discards the initial ``x``, ``y``, ``z`` passed into the function.

Comment: You are right. I edit my answer.